# How to constraint the center of an image between two layouts android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

i need to do as shown in the screenshot, but I do not understand how to do it. I tried to connect with `baseline`, but it didn't work.

My code here:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rl_bar">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/elegant_black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_layout">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:src="@color/elegant_black"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i do this?

Screenshot example:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. Try this. Cheers.

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@color/elegant_black"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_layout" />
```

Comment: it works, thanks!